# Processing multi-dimensional arrays without loop

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I need your advice and help

i fetched an array of data from the database and i want to process each element one by one without using foreach loop, something like

pop element a and process it, when finished
pop element b and process it, when finished
pop element b and process it

until the array become empty then the script can exit

currently i`m looping through the data using foreach loop but things are not working find.

```
$loaded_message = $this->lib->load_queued_messages();

                if(count($loaded_message) == 0) {
                    die ('Nothing to do');
                }

               foreach($loaded_message as $tosend)
               {


                if($this->lib->send_sms($tosend['from'], $tosend['msg'], explode(',', $tosend['numbers']), $tosend['owner'], $tosend['qid']))
                {

                    // Remove the message from queue
                    $this->lib->remove_msg_from_queued_message($tosend['qid']);
                    $this->lib->log('message #' . $tosend['qid']. ' sent and removed from queue', $tosend['owner']);
                }else{
                    $this->lib->log('SENDING_ERROR: message #' . $tosend['qid']. ' not sent and remain in the queue for#', $tosend['owner']);
                }
               }
```

Inside the log table i discovered that entry was made for wrong message id and it seems like message was sent to wrong number but it does not.

Comment: post what you have that is not working, so that someone can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Pardon the question, why are you avoiding the loop?

Comment: Post updated with sample code. thanks to @Damien and @Mat for your fast reply

Comment: Even with pop element you need a loop, a while loop. Pseudocode: while(!array_empty()) $tmpElem = pop_element;

Comment: You could consider using an SPL stack - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.splstack.php - but you're still going to have to loop until it's empty

Comment: thanks to everyone, i fixed the bug, the problem was from another log class, all i need was to reset an array so previous elements are not re-logged and that`s all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi mate you can use something like

```
while(sizeof($yourarray)) {
  $result = array_pop(yourarray);
  ...yourprocessing_here(...);
}
```

hope this helps :)